# MySql Insert and Select All In One

Tags: mysql, select, insert

What I want to do is insert a record into a table and return the primary key in a select statement in the same query. The primary key is a auto increment and I would like to get this value to send to another function.

Comment: And how exactly would you "like" to do that?

Comment: RTLM: http://php.net/mysqli_insert_id

Comment: You can use LAST_INSERT_ID() function to get last inserted increment ID

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do both of these in one query.  What you can do instead is use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) in your second query.

```
INSERT INTO tableA(rowA, rowB) VALUES('a', 'b');

SELECT * FROM tableB WHERE rowID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which inserts and returns the Id Value if the new data row, something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION INSERTANDRETURN(Data to enter as parameters)
  RETURNS INT
  DETERMINISTIC
   BEGIN
    DECLARE id INT;
    -- Insert data
    SET id = last id according to Maxvalue or last inserted data
    RETURN id;
   END
```

See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) for further reading about procedures and functions